# Convert any time format in milliseconds with C#

Tags: c#, time, milliseconds

I have a time in this format:
00:02:13,512
Is there a method in C# that can convert this time to milliseconds (and vice versa) or must i do it manually?

Comment: A Time is a point in time - milliseconds is a duration.  Can you be more specific on what you're looking for?  Milliseconds since midnight?

Comment: Milliseconds since 00:00:00,000

Comment: So is the `00:02:13,512` in a `TimeSpan` value, in a string, or a part of a `DateTime` (use `.TimeOfDay` in the latter case)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `TimeSpan` to store this information. You can use `TimeSpan.ParseExact` like:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:02:13,512", 
                                  @"hh\:mm\:ss\,fff", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can get TotalMilliseconds using [`TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
var totlaMilliseconds = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
```

This would give you back `133512.0` if you just need to Millisecond part then you can use `ts.Milliseconds;` which would give you `512`

Comment: I think this is exactly what OP wants. `+1`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try as soon as possible.

Comment: @AsAs, `string str = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\,fff");` would give you the same back , you can also access `ts.TotalHours` etc to make your own string.